# How to register listening for any Contact changes on android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

How to register listening for any Contact **(add/remove contact, change in email/phone**) changes on android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ContentObservers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) for listening on `content://contacts/people` URIs (`Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI`).